# JPA - How to get any produced sql code programmatically?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, generated-code

JPA gurus, let say I have the following entity :

```
@Entity
class MyEntity {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    // setters and getters here
}
```

through JPA on an Oracle database something similar would be generated :

```
CREATE TABLE MyEntity {
    -- table definition generated by JPA provider goes here
}
```

How can I get the code generated by the JPA provider ?

If it's not possible to get the sql code in a standard way defined by JPA,
how can I achieve this with `Hibernate 3.6.8.Final` or greater ?

Comment: Note, that it's not the `JPA` duty to generate DDL. Some providers such as `Hiberhate` allow schema generation, some don't. Anyways, your question has nothing to do with JPA.

Comment: You are right ... it's the JPA provider duty !

Comment: According to the JPA spec, `It is permitted, but not required, that DDL generation be supported by an implementation of this specification`. So your real question should probably sound more specific, like `How do I access the DDL generated by Hibernate from JPA entities?`

Comment: I have updated the title to be clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at classes in hbm2ddl package

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/tool/hbm2ddl/package-summary.html

Especially SchemaExport class.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <property name="show_sql">true</property>
```

In hibernate config